# Continuous integration and Automated testing strategy

Tags: asp.net, continuous-integration, teamcity

I’m working in a company that uses Continuous Integration (TeamCity).  Every time someone does a check in the CI software starts a build and  runs all the Unit/Automated Test . The problem is that we got more than 7000 unit tests + 756 automated tests (used to test the JavaScript as we got a very complex UI logic for making calculation etc). As you can imaging every time someone does a check in the all process takes more than 2 hours to go through all the steps (build-unitest-automated test) so that I need to wait that much before I can get a result to understand if my check in has broken perhaps an automated test or a unit test. Worst situation is when more than one people check in something so that TeamCity start queue up the build and before I can get a valid result (udated) I can wait up to half day ! what strategy should we adopt to speed up a bit this process?  Is it a best practice run all the automated tests even against a little change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would look at breaking up your test suite in two ways - with the goal of making it so you and your team can check in, go get a cup of coffee and have some meaningful feedback from team city when you get back to your desk.

1. decide what you really want to test on every commit, move the remaining tests to a suite that runs at a scheduled interval (hourly, nightly - whatever works for you).
2. If the set of tests agreed upon to run every commit is still large - break that set up and distribute across multiple nodes running in parallel.

You may also want to beef up your CI machine, depending on the nature of your stuff have the working directory for the tests live in tmpfs (RAM disk).

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to talk in theory, I have yet to put it into practice but CI is on my goals to have up and humming by the end of the summer.

From statements I've seen made by the people that have earned the most respect from me in developers the most common element for CI I've seen in regards to the testing strategy is to split your tests into Long Running and Short Running.

Then you would want to configure that standard check ins kick off the short running test for basic validation of the solution. Then on the nightly builds, and for deployment builds is the only time you NEED to run the full test suite to give your validation of regression tests.

---

Aside/Alternate answer: Seeing as I haven't setup CI for myself yet, I had never understood the TeamCity business model that they making the pricing based on build agents. Now I understand why multiple build agents really start to matter if your test suite takes that long, being able to run 5 builds at once becomes much more important. So one option could be to just spend more money and stick a band-aid on the bullet hole for now.

Answer (score 0):

Continuous Integration works best with a distributed version control system like [Git](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git_%28software%29) or [Mercurial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercurial).

Every developer can check in often into their local repository without triggering the whole integration and UI testing ceremony all the time.

Once a feature is finished locally, it can be checked in to the central repository. Thus the CI server runs all the time-consuming tests only when new features and/or fixes have been added.

Comment: I don't think they are keen to change their source version control which at the moment is P4V :-(
Any other suggestions?
+ 1 anyway for the idea

Comment: while your statements are true, the pain points Massimiliano has would still be evident any time he wanted to push to the primary repository. While a DVCS might make his development experience better that he can check in locally instead of wait wait wait commit, that doesn't alleviate the OPs problem in any form.

Comment: @Massimiliano as strange as it might sound, if you would like to version your work between committing to the P4V CVS you could use Mercurial or Git locally without any issue or needing to change your solution since they work entirely off the file system. Just make sure you create the repository at the folder level above the solution root folder to prevent any accidental file additions to the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using pre-tested commits? If you run a remote run build (without committing in to VCS), you can be sure that you didn't break anything in VCS (just because you didn't commit yet). And you can continue working without problems. If the build is successful, you can commit your change (even if you made some other changes in the same files) - if you commit via TeamCity's plugin it will commit exactly the code you sent to the server for the testing.

This way, you don't have to wait until TeamCity's build has finished to continue working with it.

Disclaimer: I'm a TeamCity developer.